# ocultar id de url en php

Tags: php, url

quisiera saber si hay una forma de ocultar o encriptar el id, ya que me aparece en la url de esta manera: http://localhost/iedan/views/detallesTarea.php?id_tarea=69

vi que se podía con base64_encode como en este ejemplo:

`<?='<td href="eaxample.com/imagen?id='.base64_encode($id).'>Ver imagen</td>'?>`

pero intente replicarlo en mi código y no supe como hacerlo de la manera correcta, por el momento lo tengo de la siguiente forma:

`<a href="modificarTarea.php?id_tarea=<?php echo $mostrar ['id_tarea']; ?>">`

gracias.

Comment: Te tira algún error con tu código actual ? Has intentado usar el [Encode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.base64-encode.php) en una variable y luego insertarla en la url?

Comment: @ignacionicolasdonosofiguero el código actual funciona normalmente, es decir me muestra el id en la url pero no lo esta ocultando o encriptando, al intentar usar el encode me da errores de sintaxis ya que no se la manera correcta de adaptarlo.

Comment: Acabo de probar lo siguiente 
    $id = 51;
    $encripted = base64_encode(strval($id));
    echo $encripted
Y me funciono bien, me puedes decir que tan diferente esta este codigo del tuyo?